# Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR invalid password

Tags: azure-redis-cache

Here is code snippet. Even after passing the correct name and key values, still getting the invalid password exception.

```
JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo("<name>.redis.cache.windows.net", 6380, useSsl);
    shardInfo.setPassword("<key>"); /* Use your access key. */
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
    jedis.set("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ IDE to perform this test, and it seems the IJ cached some wrong value for the key, even though the correct key is mentioned in the program.

Build-> Clean Project & Build->Rebuild Project from IJ, and re-run the program resolved the issue.